# Time limit for "background thread" in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

In GAE, web requests are limited to 30 seconds, and tasks are limited to 10 minutes. However, [background threads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.background_thread.background_thread) exist as well. According to their documentation:

> Background threads created using this API do not inherit the context of their creator and do not need to end before the creator request completes.

Does this mean that they have no time limit? What about their memory limits?

As far as my own research goes, the only place I find background threads mentioned in the docs (other than the module documentation above) is in ["backends"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Background_threads) documentation. Backends are deprecated (in favor of modules, which are now renamed to services, it would appear... and yet all of these terms are used freely in the docs!). So I don't know how much of that page is applicable, and even then, it doesn't mention whether background threads have time limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Background Threads have no limit but they have to run on Manual Scaling or Basic Scaling Instances and they can 
only get as much memory the instance offers.

The official documentation suggests not to use Background Threads and to use alternatives like Queues.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#threads

Tasks Queues can also run on Manual Scaling and Basic Scaling Instances and they have a time limit of 24 hours

See the overview Table here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes

Comment: This has since been deprecated. Java 8 supports threads and no mention of using task queues over threads is listed in the docs.